# Update multiple fields in Elastic c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, elasticsearch

How we can update Multiple values in elastic using  C#

Sample document
{
"id": 1,
"name":"Test",
"city":"Georgia",
"country":"US",
"email":"test@mail.com"
"phone": "3434535"
}

```
Here just i want to update only name and city 

i have tried this 

var updateResponse = client.Update<MyDocument, object>(new DocumentPath<MyDocument>(1), u => u
    .Doc(new MyDocument
    {
        name = "Test1",
        country = "Canada",
       
    })
    .Index("test")
);
How we can use UpdateQuery to do the same
```

Comment: You are talking about the NEST client? And are you asking about updating multiple documents or just multiple fields in one document or both?